# How to get ajax response without html page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, ajax

I have a problem like this.

```
<select onchange="select()" id="select">
    <option value="1">test 1</option>
    <option value="2">test 2</option>
</select>
```

I take the value of #select with javascript and send with ajax to php

```
  var clientVal = $('#select').val();
  $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'../../works/addWork.php',
        dataType:'JSON',
        data:{
            client_val:clientVal
        },
        success:function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        }
    })
```

php

```
 $client_id = $_POST['client_val'];
$row_subClient = $conn->query("SELECT `id`,`name` from `subClient` where `client_id`=$client_id");
$sub_client_arr = [];

while($result_client = $row_subClient->fetch_assoc()){
    $sub_client_arr[$result_client['id']] = $result_client['name'];
}
echo json_encode($sub_client_arr);
```

There isn't any problem here.After getting in php,I select from database my  datas.There isn't problem here too.But when I do json_encode($array),and console.log(res) to javascript.It gives me back all html page with my arrays.Where is my problem,that I get with html? Please help me.Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you post the PHP?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing ../../works/addWork.php

Comment: $client_id = $_POST['client_val'];
    $row_subClient = $conn->query("SELECT `id`,`name` from `subClient` where `client_id`=$client_id");
    $sub_client_arr = [];
    
    while($result_client = $row_subClient->fetch_assoc()){
        $sub_client_arr[$result_client['id']] = $result_client['name'];
    }
    echo json_encode($sub_client_arr);

Comment: Looking at your question, most probably, you are not setting the header to json.
Please refer this answer to see how to set header as json.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script

Comment: header('Content-Type: application/json'); Add this in addwork.php, please find my answer below

Answer (score 2):

So you have added dataType:'JSON' which expects JSON data from the addwork.php file.

So in your adwork.php file if you have an array data then you need to make a json data which can be done in php with json_encode.

```
$arrayData = array(
'key' => 'value',
'key' => 'value',
'key' => 'value',
'key' => 'value'
);

To encode this in php you can use 

header('Content-Type: application/json');
return json_encode($arrayData);
```

Okay so another problem as Sergej said the problem might be as follows in your php file your doing

```
echo json_encode($arraDetails);

<html content below here>
```

You can over come that problem by

```
echo json_encode($arraDetails);
exit; // This will make sure that the below content won't execute
<html content below here>
```

Comment: The header is not necessarily required if `dataType: "json"` is set. And if your code is not surrounded by a function, you have to `echo` the encoded json instead of returning it.

Comment: I had similar type of problem. Where I wanted JSON data which should return from my php. When I added the above approach it solved my issue. So thought I should add that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put exit; after you print the json in the backend. The HTML is sent by backend. So the problem is definately there.

Comment: I dont understand.Please tell me details.

Comment: What he meant is even after returning your data or echoing, its passing down to the code below.